# Can i have a variable parameter in csv Data set configer in jmeter

Tags: testing, jmeter

[image]

This is my test plan where the first CVS data set configure is like

[image]

And the Second CSV data Set configure is like

[image]

I want to read a file that contains all the file names and go inside each file and read each line and form a http request and hit the server.
I don't want to use loop controller because i need concurrency in terms of requests in a single file.

Say the file1.csv contains 10 lines which is equals to 10 http calls and i have 5 threads then the threads have to handle the 10 calls concurrently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) is a [**Configuration Element**](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#config_elements), as per documentation:

> Configuration elements can be used to set up defaults and variables for later use by samplers. Note that these elements are processed at the start of the scope in which they are found, i.e. before any samplers in the same scope.

JMeter test elements [execution order](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder) looks as follows:

```
0. Configuration elements
1. Pre-Processors
2. Timers
3. Sampler
4. Post-Processors (unless SampleResult is null)
5. Assertions (unless SampleResult is null)
6. Listeners (unless SampleResult is null)
```

So your `${file}` variable will be null unless a Sampler is executed and 2nd CSV Data Set Config will be initialized **before** any sampler execution.

If you want to read data from files dynamically consider using [__StringFromFile()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) or [__CSVRead()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) functions instead.

Functions are being evaluated at the time they're being called so basically you can put a function anywhere in your script. Check out [How to Pick Different CSV Files at JMeter Runtime](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-pick-different-csv-files-at-jmeter-runtime) article for more details if needed.